# $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} |f- \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} f| = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} |f- \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} f| = 0$

Can I use the Monotone convergence theorem besides the L'Hopital theorem to show this? with $t=1/n$

Comment: Do you assume some regularity for $f$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, $f$ is only Lesbesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Then why do you want to use L'Hopital?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I am just thinking and not sure.

Comment: L'Hopital assumes differentiability, that is why I thought continuity would be a given :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I see, I apologize for that, but I think your argument still work, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't work at all. The whole proof crucially relies on the continuity. Maybe I can come up with a fix.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, you should recover your deleted solution as peek-a-boo has given a counterexample to the general situation.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Solution:**

Note that
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}\left|f-\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}f\right|\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}|f-f(r)|+\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}\left|f(r)-\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}f\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}|f-f(r)|+\left|f(r)-\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}f\right|.
\end{align*}
By Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem one has for a.e. $r$ that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{r-t}^{r+t}|f-f(r)|\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
and hence the proposition is true for a.e. $r$.

For a fixed $b$, I have no solution.

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, let $b$ be arbitrary, and $f(x)$ be $1,0,-1$ if $x>b, x=b,x<b$ respectively. Then, the limit in question is equal to $1$. This shows the statement is false in general. So, one should assume $b$ is a Lebesgue point for $f$ (or simply that $f$ is continuous at $b$).

Answer (score 1):

I consider the case when $f$ is continuous, then general case is covered in the answer below..

We have
$$ \vert f(x)-\frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} f(y) dy \vert 
=\vert \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} (f(x)-f(y)) dy\vert 
\leq \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert dy
\leq \sup_{y\in (b-t,b+t)} \vert f(x)-f(y)\vert.$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t}  \vert f(x)-\frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} f(y) dy \vert dx 
\leq \frac{1}{2t} \int_{b-t}^{b+t} \sup_{y\in (b-t,b+t)} \vert f(x)-f(y)\vert
\leq \sup_{x,y\in (b-t,b+t)} \vert f(x)-f(y)\vert.$$
However, if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets and hence you obtain that the RHS of the last inequality goes to zero, which yields the claim.

Comment: $f$ is only Lesbesgue integrable on  $\mathbb{R}$